# Android Java create dynamic textviews

Tags: java, android, textview

I am getting a json array through my api.
I want to display the data in my view, but I do not know how to generate for example textviews and put the data inside each views. (My wish would be to show the data in something like a html table, but at the moment I am fine to understand how to put the data in dynamic textviews
)

```
 String id         = jsonobject.getString("id");
 String category   = jsonobject.getString("category");
 String content    = jsonobject.getString("content");
```

Do hold the correct data.

Following method is in my Async task:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result != "error") {

            JSONArray jsonArray;
            TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jokeContent);
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id         = jsonobject.getString("id");
                    String category   = jsonobject.getString("category");
                    String content    = jsonobject.getString("content");

                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toasty.error(context, "Catch , test1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toasty.error(context, "Else , test2!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start by adding a table layout  to your Layout, next create a row on your layout files something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/row">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="20"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="20"
    android:text="TextView" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="20"
    android:text="TextView" />
</TableRow>
```

then you can add the rows and fill them with info like this on your activity by using an inflater

```
for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String id         = jsonobject.getString("id");
    String category   = jsonobject.getString("category");
    String content    = jsonobject.getString("content");

    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableRow tablerow = (TableRow)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, tableLayout,false);
    ((TextView)tablerow.findViewById(R.id.ID)).setText(id);
    ((TextView)tablerow.findViewById(R.id.Category)).setText(category);
    ((TextView)tablerow.findViewById(R.id.Content)).setText(content);
    tableLayout.addView(tablerow);
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to create a textView and update it after getting a response of your Asynk task.
The idea is..

1. Create Activity (e.x. Main Activity), create AsynkTask
2. Create layout and TextView inside
3. Find TextView in Activity and not in Asynk task. In your case

   TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jokeContent);
4. Put data to some common resource from AsyncTask and get them in Activity.

E.x. (Kotlin) through interface

```
interface AsyncResponse {
    fun finishProcess(result: String)
}
```

...

```
class AsyncExecuter constructor(val asyncResp: AsyncResponse)
```

...

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: String) { //AsynkTask
    super.onPostExecute(result)
    asyncResp.finishProcess(result) //asynkResp is interfase which is put to AsynkTask constructor

}
```

Activity implements my own AsynkResp interface and calls AsynkTask

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    AsyncExecuter(this).execute()
}
```

And implement method from interface in activity where update TextView

```
   override fun finishProcess(output: String) {
        textview?.text = output
    }
```

The main idea is manipulation with UI should be done from Activity and not from parallel threads.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, i have created a list for a prefixed array list. Instead of XML i use java to create dynamic views.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { String[] wordlist = new String[] { "Shahi Paneer", "Shahi Thali","Shahi Parantha","Kadai Paneer","Mix Parantha", }; @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ListView list = new ListView(this); list.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(240,255,255) ); list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, wordlist)); setContentView(list); } private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> { public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] strings) { super(context, -1, -1, strings); } @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/BLESD___ .ttf"); Typeface rupeeSymbol = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/IndianRupee.ttf"); Typeface maze = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/The Heart Maze Demo.ttf"); Typeface epicselfie = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/My Epic Selfie Demo.ttf"); Typeface novaoval = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/NovaOval.ttf"); LinearLayout listLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this); listLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams( AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); listLayout.setId(View.generateViewId()); listLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); LinearLayout layout1 = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this); layout1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); listLayout.addView(layout1); ImageView imgView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this); imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.thali); imgView.setPadding(20,20,20,10); imgView.setAdjustViewBounds(true); layout1.addView(imgView); LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this); layout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); listLayout.addView(layout2); TextView listText = new TextView(MainActivity.this); listText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); listText.setPadding(30,0,0,0); listText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 40); listText.setTypeface(maze,maze.BOLD); listText.setId(View.generateViewId()); layout2.addView(listText); LinearLayout cartlayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this); cartlayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); cartlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); cartlayout.setPadding(0,0,30,0); cartlayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); // layout3.setPadding(0,10,0,20); layout2.addView(cartlayout); ImageView addCartView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this); addCartView.setImageResource(R.drawable.add); // addCartView.setPadding(200,0,0,0); cartlayout.addView(addCartView); TextView NOFProd = new TextView(MainActivity.this); NOFProd.setId(View.generateViewId()); NOFProd.setTypeface(rupeeSymbol); NOFProd.setPadding(10,20,10,0); NOFProd.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25); // NOFProd.s NOFProd.setText("0"); cartlayout.addView(NOFProd); ImageView removeCartView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this); removeCartView.setImageResource(R.drawable.remove); // removeCartView.setPadding(20,5,20,0); cartlayout.addView(removeCartView); TextView descText = new TextView(MainActivity.this); descText.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY); descText.setPadding(30,0,0,0); descText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20); descText.setTypeface(epicselfie); descText.setText("Swadist Bhojan"); descText.setId(View.generateViewId()); listLayout.addView(descText); // price and others Textview LinearLayout layout3 = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this); layout3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); layout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); layout3.setPadding(0,10,0,20); listLayout.addView(layout3); TextView pricesymbol = new TextView(MainActivity.this); pricesymbol.setId(View.generateViewId()); pricesymbol.setTypeface(rupeeSymbol); pricesymbol.setPadding(30,10,0,0); pricesymbol.setText("`"); layout3.addView(pricesymbol); TextView priceText = new TextView(MainActivity.this); priceText.setId(View.generateViewId()); priceText.setTypeface(novaoval); priceText.setPadding(10,10,0,0); priceText.setText(": 200"); layout3.addView(priceText); TextView rating = new TextView(MainActivity.this); rating.setId(View.generateViewId()); rating.setPadding(50,0,0,0); rating.setTypeface(novaoval); rating.setText("Rating : 3.5"); layout3.addView(rating); TextView any = new TextView(MainActivity.this); any.setPadding(50,0,0,0); any.setTypeface(novaoval); any.setId(View.generateViewId()); any.setText("anything "); layout3.addView(any); listText.setText(super.getItem(position)); return listLayout; } } }
```